# How do I use views to create a block that display image and title

Tags: views, files

[image]

How do I use views to create a block that display image and title.
The image is using IMCE module.

I have try create a views, select “node”, under "fields" section select "content" but can't select the imce image.

What is wrong?

Comment: SO the image is not inserted as an independent field ?

Comment: @AlirezaTabatabaeian  The image is insert with module imce. https://www.drupal.org/project/imce

Comment: @AlirezaTabatabaeian The image is not inserted as independent field. It is using imce module to upload the image. Can't the views display the image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use CCK to upload image.
In Views, display the image with CCK. (Filter > Content:Image)